# Is it possible for call the foxpro .prg directly from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-foxpro

I tried this code below:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Fox As New VisualFoxpro.FoxApplication
        Fox.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Temp"
        Fox.DoCmd("Do TestAutomation.prg")
    End Sub
End Module
```

But I don't understand that why the `VisualFoxpro.FoxApplication` can't be recognize by the Visual Studio.
I tried to import `System.Resources` or `System.Runtime`, and still can't work.

So did I miss out something or it just can't work?

One more thing, Can it run standalone after compiled in visual studio without vfp?

Comment: Yes, you missed something.  Follow [Cindy's instructions](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/379697-run-program-file-visual-foxpro-using-vb-net) on how to add the reference.

Comment: I just can't get the point, how to add a reference to the vfp type library? Is it add it into the visual studio?

Comment: Well, "is it add it" stumps me too.  Project > Add Reference > click the Browse button.  It is never going to work if you don't have FoxPro installed on your machine.

Comment: You'd need a reference to the VisualFoxPro class you are referring to.  The only DLL I've worked with for this is the VFP ODBC driver.   However, [this may help you on this task](http://www.foxcentral.net/microsoft/NETforVFPDevelopers_Chapter15.htm)

Comment: I added the vfp.exe into reference and it can work on my computer, but I copied to other computer, it can't run the module. I also tried vfpodbc.dll and it can't work. Is there an other method that I can use .prg without installing vfp9?

Comment: No, you need VFP to be present to run a PRG. If you have an EXE, you only need the runtimes. (That's a big deal because you need a license for VFP.EXE, but not for the runtimes.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use a tricky way to reach the goal I want to achieve. Create a new project in foxpro, then add a program to it, finally test it and build it.

On the vb.net, use the following code to call the .exe file:

`Process.Start("file location")`

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of how we use VB.Net to launch a legacy VFP application...

```
' --- Create a VFP Object within the VB.Net code ---
Dim oVFP = CreateObject("VisualFoxPro.Application")
   ' --- Issue VFP Commands via the VFP Object ---
   With oVFP
        .DoCmd("PUBLIC RETURNVAL")
        .DoCmd("DO " & PathToVFPPrint & "VFPPRINT.PRG WITH " & ParamList)
        .doCmd("CLOSE DATABASES ALL")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ReturnVal = .Eval("RETURNVAL")
    End With
    oVFP.Quit()
    oVFP = Nothing
```

Good Luck